# MediaPlayer is not playing?

Tags: android, media-player

when the sound playback is repeated for a long time. when the example is clicked 10 times He does not play. what is the reason why it plays when you restart the application

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.click);
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(7f, 7f);
            mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: from where you call above code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mediaPlayer.reset()` will help you!

Ex:

```
public static void startSound(Context context, int soundResId) {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundResId);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```